# How to show X and Y are bi-variate normal in this case?

Tags: normal-distribution, bivariate-distributions

Assume $Z_1$, $Z_2$ and $Z_3$ are independent standard normally distributed $N(0,1)$. We have $X=Z_1+Z_2$ and $Y=Z_1+Z_3$. Need to show $X$ and $Y$ are bivariate normally distributed with $((0,0)', \Sigma=\begin{bmatrix}
                                   2 & 1 \\
    1&2
\end{bmatrix})$

Always work with problems with two $Z$ variables. Any suggestion?

Comment: Are the $Z_i$ assumed independent?

Comment: Yes, All 3 $Z$s are independent of each other

Comment: Then you are all set: they are jointly multivariate normal, $(X,Y)$ is an affine transormation of them, and the recipe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Affine_transformation applies.